# Android 6.0 "Storage" permission shown without even declaring in manifest

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an application that uses these permissions:

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <!--normal permission-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> <!--normal permission-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> <!--normal permission-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> <!--dangerous permission-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <!--dangerous permission-->
```

Android 6.0 shows "Storage" and "Location" permissions for my app settings. It is ok. But when I **delete all** permissions from manifest, Android still shows "**Storage**" permission for my app. Where does this permission come from?

When I run this command for my apk:

```
aapt dump badging myapk
```

It shows

```
sdkVersion:'14'
targetSdkVersion:'23'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
```

But I haven't defined any storage related permissions!

Comment: but lib used by you has ... asked bazillion times

Comment: See also this blog post: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for great post! 
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0' was the case

Comment: IIRC, if you move up to 8.1.0, the storage permissions will not be needed on API Level 19+ devices. Presumably, they switched to `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, I will try. I need write_storage permission only for cache. But it seems that for some Loillipop devices getExternalCacheDir() still need write storage permission. So I have the permission in my manifest as    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>  What can you say about it?

Comment: @android_dev: "But it seems that for some Loillipop devices getExternalCacheDir() still need write storage permission" -- it shouldn't, as AFAIK that's not something tied to specific devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok. I have tried to update to 8.1.0 and no change.
from manifest merger:
uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
ADDED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0]

Comment: @CommonsWare i have another question regarding new permission model. I have opened an issue. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189121